# how to run junit test classes in parallel but list a few exceptions gradle

Tags: gradle, junit4

I would like to run all junit test classes in parallel(due to setup in each test, I DO NOT want tests in a single class running in parallel or they would step on each other with mock changes of state)

I however have some selenium tests that must be run in series but can be run while the other tests are running.

1. Can gradle run test classes in parallel without running tests within a class in parallel(again due to shared state)
2. Can we exclude some tests that need to be run in sequence

thanks,
Dean

Comment: When it comes to spock you can annotate a class with `@Stepwise` and even if in the presence of parallel runner specs from a single suite will be run in order they are declared. Do you also need dependencies between suites? So then answer to 1 is probaly yes, when it comes to 2 you need to change the design.

Comment: May be adding different test suits and run those parallel ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm more Maven oriented, but shouldn't creating a new task for gradle and setting values to properties maxParallelForks and forkEvery (probably this property should be set to 1) do the job?

Something like [example](http://mrhaki.blogspot.rs/2010/11/gradle-goodness-running-tests-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per their documentation and some of their forum threads, if you are running test in parallel then it spawns new processes based on your `maxParallelForks` property mentioned and in that spawned processes it will run `forkEvery` no. of test classes. You can run some of the tasks in sequence by mentioning them as dependent on one other.